# Deeplinking in GWT (IE)

Tags: gwt, hyperlink, deep-linking

I want to support deeplinks in my gwt application. E.g. if a request is received like http://myhost/myapp/#deeplink123 I want to do something with "123" (as you know if http://myhost/myapp/deeplink123 without hash is received the hole site is reloaded). I added the history frame to my start html site and a value change handler in my entrypoint class:

```
<iframe src="javascript:''" id="__gwt_historyFrame" style="width:0;height:0;border:0"> </iframe>

History.addValueChangeHandler(new ValueChangeHandler<String>() {
    public void onValueChange(ValueChangeEvent<String> event) {
        String token = event.getValue();
        // do something with token
    });
```

This works fine in firefox, but in internet explorer the onValueChange-Event is not fired if a deep link is entered into the browser address bar.

Dou you have any ideas how i can recognize deeplinks in IE?

Thanks in advance - Max

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `History.fireCurrentHistoryState()` at the end of your applications `onModuleLoad` to inform history handlers of the initial application state.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The ValueChange-Event isn't fired anyway (IE8). It seems this is a known and unsolved problem between gwt and ie as you can see here: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=2777#c7 I'll try now the library gwt-presenter, which has an onPlaceRequest-Event, that i can use possibly for deeplinking.

Answer (score 0):

It works in IE8 if i change the line
[set-property name="user.agent" value="ie6,gecko1_8"]
to
[set-property name="user.agent" value="ie8]
in the app.gwt.xml file.

But only if a add a document type declaration like [!doctype html] in the main html site. That causes some optical problems like wrong sizes, margins and colors in my application, so there is more work to do.